# Opening database connection in controller (connection pattern)

Tags: php, design-patterns, database-connection

I've got to implement a database connection pattern. I created two classes:

- **ConnectionFactory**
- **MySQLService**

**ConnectionFactory:**

```
<?php

  class ConnectionFactory {
    protected static $connection;

    public function getConnection() {
        if (!self::$connection) {
            self::$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sapienter', "root", "admin");
        }
        return self::$connection;
    }
  }

?>
```

**MySQLService:**

```
<?php

  class MySQLService {
    protected $connectionFactory;

    public function __construct(ConnectionFactory $factory) {
      $this->connectionFactory = $factory;
    }

    public function listItemsForSharerSQL() {
      $conn = $this->connectionFactory->getConnection();
      $items = ...
      return $items;
    }
  }

?>
```

I call these methods in my controller **ItemController**:

```
<?php

require_once ROOT_DIR . "/models/Item.php";
require_once ROOT_DIR . "/ConnectionFactory.php";
require_once ROOT_DIR . "/MySQLService.php";

class ItemController {

    private $data;

    public function listItemsForSharer() {
        $connFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        $service = new MySQLService($connFactory);
        $items = $service->listItemsForSharerSQL();

        $this->data = ['items' => $items];
        return 'itemslistforsharer-view';
    }
}

?>
```

I don't like the fact that I've got to instantiate a new ConnectionFactory in my Controller. Is it a mistake? Should I change my code design?

Comment: Well, then move the construction into the constructor of the MySqlService class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mistake that you are using a Database in a Controller at all. If talking about a Controller from the MVC Architecture pattern, then its Models job to interact with the database. There should be only instances of the Models in the controllers, but not instances of the Database.

Basically in the modern MVC frameworks that Models are extending the base Model class, which has the instantiation of the database.

As I understand, `MySQLService` is something like a model since you are returning some items, it seems like you are doing DB operation and want to handle it from a controller. Instead of every model having its own constructor, you should use a base class. I would suggest something like:

```
class Model {

    protected function getAdapter() {
        $connection = new ConnectionFactory();
        return $connection->getConnection();
    }

}


class MySQLService extends Model {

    public function listItemsForSharerSQL() {
      $this->getAdapter();
      $items = ...
      return $items;
    }
}
```

So now your controller will only need

```
$service = new MySQLService();
```

Ofcourse you base class can have the `getAdapter()` method as a constructor, without any params, so you won't need to pass anything to the `MySQLService` and won't need to call `getAdapther()` in each method of `MySQLService`. Depends on your needs.

Comment: I'm trying to split Model layer between Domain objects and Data Mappers. My Domain objects (e.g. **Item**) are unaware of storage. `MySQLService` should be my Data Mapper. So I would instantiate `MySQLService` in my controller, as you propose, and then do for example: `$items = $service->findAllItems();`. Is it right?

Comment: Seems like a right decision. You just need to get rid of a constructor which accept db object params :)

Comment: For multiple instantiations it is. It's ok if you are instantiating the object from one place, i.e. if an application class instantiates all if you models, injecting them the database, but since you are using them as an independent objects, you don't need this. You now are telling the constructor, accept params only if they are object of type ConnectionFactory, thus you need ConnectionFactory being instantiated from anywhere you want to instantiate you `MySQLService` class. So you explictly make you life harder by saying this to the constructor